# r equivalent and Norton equivalent

Tags: current, norton

Can anyone explain how Norton equivalent resistance  and R equivalent which is equivalent resistance of network are different in this circuit .[image]

Comment: Also add what you have understood or which part you have been trying to understand, it helps others in knowing where you have been confused or stuck.

Answer (score 1):

This circuit can be represented by a Thevenin Voltage source connected in series with a Thevenin resistor. In Norton equivalent instead of a voltage source you have a current source and a resistor connected in parallel. So you can switch between the Thevenin and Norton equaivalent circuits by using the source transformation method

Answer (score 0):

The Norton resistance is obtained by looking from the load side, that is short your voltage source shown in the image and put a voltage source at the load which is the AB net line in your case. now after doing so calculate the resistance of the circuit with the curent entering the R3 resistor. This totall resistance is the norton/thevenin resistance. Rnorton = R3 + (R2 || Ri+R1)   .

Have the circuit that you have now and calculate the resistance that should be your usual equivalent resistance. Req = (Ri + R1) +(R2 || R3)